# Is a two hour layover at London, UK Heathrow too short?

Tags: layovers, lhr, short-connections

Plan to fly from USA to Switzerland through London Heathrow. There is only 1.5-2h to catch connecting flight. The terminal for arrival and departure is the same.

Is it too tight?

Comment: Personally, I think 1,5 hours should be fine as it is within the same terminal.

Comment: purely one man's opinion: with Heathrow, you can never have enough time. for me I would be concerned, it's a bit short.  Also, is there any way at all to change your flight?  Heathrow Airport is the single worst thing in the universe: avoid it at all cost and in any way possible.

Comment: I agree with Muller, 1.5-2 hours within the same terminal is fine.